# Do strcmp and strstr test binary equivalence?

Tags: c, string, locale

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/security-considerations--international-features

This webpage makes me wonder.
Apparently some windows api may consider two strings equal when they are actually different byte sequences.
I want to know how C standard library behaves in this respect.

in other words, does `strcmp(a,b)==0` imply `strlen(a)==strlen(b)&&memcmp(a,b,strlen(a))==0`?
and what about other string functions, including wide character versions?

edit:

for example, `CompareStringW` equates L"\x00C5" and L"\x212B"
`printf("%d\n",CompareStringW(LOCALE_INVARIANT,0,L"\x00C5",-1,L"\x212B",-1)==CSTR_EQUAL);` outputs 1

what I'm asking is whether C library functions never behave like this

Comment: That page is talking about `lstrcmp()`, which takes locale into consideration. Regular `strcmp()` doesn't do this.

Comment: @user42471 How can two strings be equal if their lengths are different? Think about this yourself.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If there are two byte sequences that are different lengths but considered equivalent. E.g. one is encoded with UTF-8 and the other with UTF-16.

Comment: @Barmar strcmp uses plain characters.

Comment: @Barmar but stringwise they have the same length.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: [Source code for `strcmp`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcmp.c.html).

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/strcoll.html

Comment: Using a locale-aware comparison function, the strings "schön" and "schön" might compare equal, even though they have different lengths.  The strings "fußball" and "FUSSBALL" might compare as case-insensitively equal, even though they have different lengths and look pretty different.  (That's because there is no upper-case form for ß, so you have to use SS.  In the case of schön vs. schön, you can't see it without special tools, but one uses U+00F6 Latin Small Letter O with Diaeresis, while the other uses U+006F Latin Small Letter O plus U+0308 Combining Diaeresis.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Cast in referenced code: [`c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcmp.c.html) appears useless.  Any idea why it is there?

Comment: @chux: https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/u7zaqy/whats_with_all_the_casting_to_unsigned_char_in/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks.  Unfortunately most of that thread talks about the  casting in `const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;`, which is necessary for correct functionality.  The cast in `c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;` remains unnecessary as `*s1++` returns an `unsigned char` and so that cast does _nothing_.  If I had an account there, I would post a correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular string functions operate byte-by-byte. The [specification](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4) says:

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as `unsigned char`) that differ in the objects being compared.

`strcmp()` and `memcmp()` do the same comparisons. The only difference is that `strcmp()` uses the null terminators in the strings as the limit, `memcmp()` uses a parameter for this, and `strncmp()` takes a limit parameter and uses whichever comes first.

The wide string function [specification](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.4.4) says:

> Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the functions described in this subclause order two wide characters the same way as two integers of the underlying integer type designated by `wchar_t`.

`wcscmp()` doesn't say otherwise, so it's also comparing the wide characters numerically, not by converting their encodings to some common character representations. `wcscmp()` is to `wmemcmp()` as `strcmp()` is to `memcmp()`.

On the other hand, `wcscoll()` compares the strings as interpreted according to the `LC_COLLATE` category of the current locale. So this may not be equivalent to `memcmp()`.

For other functions you should check the documentation to see whether they reference the locale.

Comment: Some functions are even more complicated for example by using "string sort" techniques

Comment: @0___________ Right.  So I can imagine that `lstrcmp("schön", "schön")` might return 0 even though the bytes are different, and I can imagine that `lstrcmpi("fußball", "FUSSBALL")` might return 0 even though the strings look different

Answer (score 3):

1. two strings using different encodings can be the same even if their byte representation are different.
2. standard library `strcmp` does compare plain "character" strings and in this case **`strcmp(a,b)==0 implies strlen(a)==strlen(b)&&memcmp(a,b,strlen(a))==0`**
3. Functions like `wcscmp` require both strings to be encoded the same way, so their byte representation should be the same.

Comment: Is `strcmp` actually guaranteed to consider the full range of `char` values?

Comment: @EugeneSh. as far as I know yes as the comparison is done using unsigned characters (at least POSIX)

Comment: Yep. Looks like it has it's base covered: *"For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and **has a different value**)."* - http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.1p3

Comment: @EugeneSh. `strcmp()` accesses the bytes as if they were `unsigned char` and the full range of `unsigned char` is considered.  Try `strcmp((char [2]){-1, 0}, (char [2]){1, 0})`.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently some windows api may consider two strings equal when they are actually different byte sequences.

Depending on context and where you got those strings from, **that would actually be the semantically correct behavor.**

There are multiple ways to *encode* certain characters. The German `'ä'`, for example. In Unicode, this could be U+00E4 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DAERHESIS, or it could be the sequence of U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS and U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A. You could desire a comparison function that actually compares these equal. Or you could have them *not* compare equal, but have a standalone function that turns one representation into the other ("normalization").

You could want a comparison function that compares `'6'` (six) as equal to `'๖'` (also six, just in Thai). ("Canonicalization")

The byte string functions (`strcmp()` etc.) are not capable of any of that. They only deal in byte sequences, and are unaware of anything I wrote above.

As for the wide string functions (`wcscmp()` etc.), well... they are not that either, really.

> in other words, does strcmp(a,b)==0 imply strlen(a)==strlen(b)&&memcmp(a,b,strlen(a))==0? and what about other string functions, including wide character versions?

**Either will test for binary equivalence**, as there are no mechanics in the C Standard Library to normalize or canonicalize strings.[1]

---

If you **are** actually dealing in *processing* strings (as opposed to just passing them through, for which C byte strings and wide strings are adequate), you should use the [ICU library](https://icu.unicode.org/), the *de facto* standard for C/C++ Unicode handling. It looks daunting but actually needs to be to handle all these things correctly.

Basically, any C/C++ API that promises to do the same is *either* using the ICU library itself, or is very likely not doing what it advertises.

[1]: Actually, `strcoll()` / `strxfrm()` and `wcscoll()` / `wcsxfrm()` actually provide enough wiggle room to squeeze in proper Unicode mechanics for collation, but I don't know of an implementation that actually bothers to do so.